# Ошибка в Xamarin.Forms System.ObjectDisposedException in Android.FastRenderers.ImageRenderer

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

У меня есть ListView со множеством строк. В DataTemplate этого ListView вложен еще один ListView в DataTemplate которого есть изображения которые загружаются из URL. При быстрой прокрутке списка изображения не успевают загружаться и приложение падает с ошибкой System.ObjectDisposedException in Android.FastRenderers.ImageRenderer.

Я нашел такую же ошибку на GitHub, ее не смогли воспроизвести, я прокомментировал пост, может будет решение.
https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/2164

Собственно вопрос, пока ошибка существует, какие есть варианты для того чтобы приложение не падало? Может как-то можно ее обработать из моего кода?

Сейчас я убрал изображения из шаблона, все работает, но это плохой выход, они там нужны.

Ниже код DataTemplate

```
public class DataViewCustomCell : ViewCell
{
    private Label _dataNameLabel, _scoreLabel;
    private Image _dataIconimage;

    public DataViewCustomCell()
    {
        Grid grid = new Grid
        {
            RowDefinitions =
            {
                new RowDefinition {Height = new GridLength(26, GridUnitType.Absolute)},
            },
            ColumnDefinitions =
            {
                new ColumnDefinition {Width = new GridLength(20, GridUnitType.Absolute)},
                new ColumnDefinition {Width = new GridLength(70, GridUnitType.Absolute)},
                new ColumnDefinition {Width = new GridLength(1, GridUnitType.Star)}
            }
        };

        grid.Children.Add(_dataIconimage = new Image()
        {
            HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center,
            VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center,
            Margin = new Thickness(2,0,2,0),
        }, 0, 0);
        grid.Children.Add(_scoreLabel = new Label { FontSize = 16, Margin = new Thickness(2, 0, 2, 0),
                VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center,
                HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Start,
                LineBreakMode = LineBreakMode.NoWrap,
            TextColor = ThemeManager.AlternativeTextColor}, 1, 0);
        grid.Children.Add(_dataNameLabel = new Label { FontSize = 16, Margin = new Thickness(2,0,2,0), 
            VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center,
            HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Start,
            LineBreakMode = LineBreakMode.NoWrap,
            TextColor = ThemeManager.TextColor}, 2, 0);
        View = grid;            
    }

    public static readonly BindableProperty DataNameProperty =
        BindableProperty.Create("DataName", typeof(string), typeof(DataViewCustomCell));

    public static readonly BindableProperty ImagePathProperty =
        BindableProperty.Create("ImagePath", typeof(ImageSource), typeof(DataViewCustomCell));

    public static readonly BindableProperty ScoreProperty =
        BindableProperty.Create("Score", typeof(string), typeof(DataViewCustomCell));

    public string DataName
    {
        get => (string)GetValue(DataNameProperty);
        set => SetValue(DataNameProperty, value);
    }

    public ImageSource ImagePath
    {
        get => (ImageSource)GetValue(ImagePathProperty);
        set => SetValue(ImagePathProperty, value);
    }

    public string Score
    {
        get => (string)GetValue(ScoreProperty);
        set => SetValue(ScoreProperty, value);
    }

    protected override void OnBindingContextChanged()
    {
        base.OnBindingContextChanged();

        if (BindingContext != null)
        {
            _dataNameLabel.Text = DataName;
            _scoreLabel.Text = Double.TryParse(Score, out double dob) ? dob.RoundString() : Score;
            _dataIconimage.Source = ImagePath;
            _dataIconimage.WidthRequest = 16;//ImageWidth;
            _dataIconimage.HeightRequest = 16; //ImageHeight;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Покажете свой код, который вызывает данную ошибку.

Comment: В блок catch нигде не входит. То что написано в теме это все что возвращает мне студия когда приложение падает. Где я могу обработать эту ошибку? Добавил DataTemplate ListView на котором возникает ошибка. Вероятно картинка загружается в ячейку которой уже нет, так как загрузка из URL.